# Clone a quote and mantain the relationship with its original quote line items

Tags: salesforce, apex

I'm trying to make a button which clones the quote and keeps the relationship with the original QuoteLineItem.
Basically I don't know how to clone related lists.
I get the id from the page with `ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');`
Then I query the fields I need to be duplicated, but when I click the button, it generates a quote without QuoteLineItems
I've already tried with `qli.clone(false,true);` method, but it doesn't work.
I hope it's clear enough.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Some code, please.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out by myself.
A quoteLineItem is the child in the relationship, so it can have one, and only one Parent.
I don't think it's possible to achieve what I wanted to do. Thanks anyway :)